# How to know the MIN_CONTAINER_SIZE of Amazon EMR instances?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hadoop2, emr

How can I get the default setting of `MIN_CONTAINER_SIZE` on Amazon EMR cluster? Since I would like to calculate the memory usage of each node on EMR by using this formula

`RAM-per-container = max(MIN_CONTAINER_SIZE, (Total Available RAM) / containers))`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In EMR 4.x the default minimum container size is 256M. But the upper bound will be limited by the memory made available to the nodemanager per instance type (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html).   The amount of memory within 256M to upper bound is then at discretion of application and is configurable per application.

If you share your overall goal regarding memory/container usage more detail can be given to maximize for your desired outcome.